# Clarification of requirements for variable arguments in c program

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm trying to reconcile the rules I find for creating variadic functions in C.  On the one hand I see explicitly stated (for example, [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm)) statements like "**just before the ellipses is always an int**".  On the other hand, I see lots of example programs, including on stackoverflow that make no mention of such a rule (or convention), and in fact work without it. And I see many of the other form (the extra int), that also seem to work. (The most common function, in fact seems to be one defined like: `int myFunc(char *format, ...)` and is used with `sprintf` or friends).

I'm trying to wrap my head around how it works so that future efforts are based upon understanding, rather than based on the use of copy/paste.  At present, for me, it might as well be a magic wand.  So in order to understand how to get the most out of the option, I need to understand the rules.  Can you help me understand why I find such conflicting requirements and why both conventions seem to work?

Thanks.

Comment: "*"just before the ellipses is always an int*". That's talking about the specific example and is not a general statement applying to all variable args. There is no general requirement for the first arg to always be an `int`.

Comment: usually, the first argument(s) (the arguments with defined types/identifiers) will be used to identify the types (and number) of the arguments that are associated with the `...`. For example: `int myprintf(const char *fmt, ...); myprintf("%f", 3.14);` or `int add_ints(int n, ...); add_ints(4, 7, -1, -1, -1);`

Comment: @pmg That's not the only way to do it. You can also use a sentinel value like `execl()`.

Comment: The arguments preceding the ellipses just need to convey enough information to allow the function to correctly invoke `va_arg` for the subsequent arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main rule regarding a variadic function is that you need *some* way of determining how many arguments you have and what the type of those arguments are, though not necessarily the way the tutorial say.

Generally, there are two ways: either one of the fixed arguments tells you the number and possibly the type of the variadic arguments, or one of the variadic arguments is a sentinel value which specifies the end of the argument list.

Examples from the standard library and POSIX:

- `printf` and family: The first argument is a format string, and the contents of this format string specify the number and type of each variadic argument.
- `execl`: The second of its two fixed arguments is the first argument of an external program to run.  If it is not NULL, variadic arguments are read as type `const char *` until it finds one that is NULL.

A variation of the first option is as you mentioned: one of the fixed arguments is the number of variadic arguments, where each variadic argument has the same predetermined type.  This is the simplest to implement, which is probably why the tutorial you linked suggested it.

Which of these you choose depends entirely on your use case.

Another interesting variation is the `open` function on Linux and similar systems.  The man pages show the following signatures:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

The actual declaration looks something like this:

```
extern int open (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...) __nonnull ((1));
```

In this case, one variadic argument is read if the `flags` parameter includes the value `O_CREAT`.

Comment: This does not speak to OP’s question about the statement “the one just before the ellipses is always an `int`”.

Comment: Thanks @dbush - I've accepted your answer.  It still looks like smoke and mirrors to me, but I'm peeling back the layers now.  I appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule in the C standard that the parameter just before `...` in a function declaration must be an `int`. The article you link to is merely referring to its particular example: When a function is declared with `(int foo, ...)`, then the first argument passed to that specific function (after conversion from whatever the actual argument is; e.g., a `char` argument will be converted to `int`) is always an `int`.

In general, you can have any types for the parameters before `...`. The only rule is there must be at least one explicit parameter before the `...`.

Comment: "*at least* one typed parameter" would be less subject to misinterpretation, I think. (Although, what type of parameter is not fixed-type?)

Comment: @rici: The variable argument parameters are not fixed types. But I changed it to “explicit parameter”.

Comment: but you still leave open the erroneous interpretation that only one such parameter is allowed  :-) ("must be one" could be read as "must be exactly one", no? "The jury must have 12 members" is not intended to mean that there could be 15. Although it might be read that way, too.